# How refactor a function vanilla js

Tags: javascript, function, refactoring

I am trying to refactor a function but can't figure out what could be the best approach for it

```
let smallNumber = 50;
let mediumNumber = 40;
let groupNumber = 35;

function price() {
  if (numberSelected <= 3) {
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "£"+(smallNumber * numberSelected).toFixed(2);
  } else if (numberSelected <= 6) {
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "£"+(mediumNumber * numberSelected).toFixed(2);
  } else if (numberSelected > 6) {
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "£"+(groupNumber * numberSelected).toFixed(2);
  }
  total.style.display = "block";
  button.style.display = "block";
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You want to refactor it...with what purpose?

Comment: just to understand how I could use ternary operator instead

Comment: I suppose it's ok if you're trying to learn ternary operators, but usually it's better to avoid them when you have to do nesting. Like it's fine for a quick if/else case, but not for multiple if/elseif/elseif/else. Anyway, ternary operators just work like: `condition ? true : false`. So `numberSelected <= 3 ? document... : numberSelected <= 6 ? document... : numberSelected > 6 ? document... : return false;` Just returning false at the end as it can't ever happen anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use ternary operator you can use this code. I add extra variable to reduce duplication of code.

```
function price() {
  let total = document.getElementById("total");
  total.style.display = "block";
  button.style.display = "block";
  let text;

  text = numberSelected <= 3 ? smallNumber :
         numberSelected <= 6 ? mediumNumber : groupNumber;

  total.innerHTML = "£" + (text * numberSelected).toFixed(2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can start by dividing your code into smaller functions

```js
const convertToPounds = (num) => "£" + num.toFixed(2);

const getNumToAdd = (input) => input <= 3 ? 50 : (input > 6 ? 35 : 40);

const getFinalPrice = (input) => convertToPounds(getNumToAdd(input) + input);

console.log(`Input: 2 Output: ${getFinalPrice(2)}`);
console.log(`Input: 10 Output: ${getFinalPrice(10)}`);
console.log(`Input: 5 Output: ${getFinalPrice(5)}`);
```

You can use the `getFinalPrice` function in your `start` function.

Answer (score 0):

Since refactoring involves changing the implementation of your code, it's a good idea to have tests in place before you start refactoring. The tests will allow you to know if the refactor changed the behavior of the code you're refactoring. That said, you could do the following:

```js
function price() {
  let selectedNumber;

  if (numberSelected <= 3) {
    selectedNumber = smallNumber;
  } else if (numberSelected <= 6) {
    selectedNumber = mediumNumber;
  } else if (numberSelected > 6) {
    selectedNumber = groupNumber;
  }

  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "£" + (selectedNumber * numberSelected).toFixed(2);

  total.style.display = "block";
  button.style.display = "block";
}
```